# Server 2016: Use DNS Policies to Allow Queries to Specific Domain from Specific Subnet

Tags: dns, powershell, windows-server-2016

On a public DNS server, I would like to create a rule using [DNS Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverqueryresolutionpolicy) to allow traffic to a specific domain **only** from specified subnets.

For example, say we have a domain `contoso.com`, but only want to allow a specific subnet to query this (*note that there are other publically-queryable domains on this server*). Using DNS policies, I can easily **block** a specific subnet from querying a specific domain, but I cannot figure out how to **allow** a specific subnet to query a specific domain.

The following works to **block**:

```coffee
Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "Disallow_Contoso" -Action IGNORE -ClientSubnet "EQ,LocalSubnet10.x" –FQDN "EQ,*.contoso.com" -PassThru
```

But the following does not work to **allow**:

```coffee
Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "Allow_Contoso" -Action ALLOW -ClientSubnet "EQ,LocalSubnet10.x" –FQDN "EQ,*.contoso.com" -PassThru
```

The error returned from Powershell on the second command is:

```coffee
Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy : Failed to create policy Allow_Contoso on DNS server DNS1. Please see internal exception for details.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "Allow_Contoso" -Action ALLOW  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Allow_Contoso:root/Microsoft/...esolutionPolicy) [Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 87,Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy
```

It seems that the `-Action ALLOW` is not allowed in this context, but I cannot confirm that based on the cryptic error message.

Comment: I'm also wondering if you cannot just remove the `–FQDN "EQ,*.contoso.com"` from the allow rule as well. So maybe `Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "Allow_Contoso" -Action ALLOW -ClientSubnet "EQ,LocalSubnet10.x" -PassThru` but you may need to add `[-ZoneScope <String>]` and/or `[-ZoneName] <String>`... with quick look over, that may or may not help you but that's my idea of some things to consider and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, the following is working:

```coffee
Add-DnsServerClientSubnet -Name "Subnet192.x" -IPv4Subnet 192.168.0.0/24
Add-DnsServerZoneScope -ZoneName "contoso.com" -Name "SpecialSubnet" -PassThru
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "contoso.com" -A -Name "test" -IPv4Address "10.10.0.1" -ZoneScope "SpecialSubnet" -PassThru
Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "SpecialPolicy" -Action ALLOW -ClientSubnet "eq,Subnet192.x" -ZoneScope "SpecialSubnet,1" -ZoneName "contoso.com" -PassThru
```

So if the querying device is outside of the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet, the native DNS zone will respond with an "A" record for `test.contoso.com` (assuming it has been manually created). If the querying device is within the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet, the policy created here will respond with `10.10.0.1` to a query for `test.contoso.com`.